# Maps API for Javascript - Change the labels of the city names

Tags: javascript, internationalization, here-api

My problem is that some Polish cities on the map have names in English. Even when I set

```
const ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(HEREmap, defaultLayers, 'pl-PL');
```

the map still displays them in English. For example: `Karków` is displayed as `Cracow`. It's not wrong name, but I want to provide to my users a proper i18n experience. Is there any way to translate those names? Or is it up to Here Maps to provide the names and I can't do anything about it?

Comment: Don't you need [H.ui.i18n.Localization("pl-PL")](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.5.0/dev_guide/topics_api/h-ui-i18n-localization.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language argument in `H.ui.UI.createDefault` is for setting the language in the default UI components, for example in the layer switcher component.

For the map data, you can take advantage of the `lg` property in the call to `platform.createDefaultLayers`, as below:

```js
let defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers({
   lg: 'pl' // set language to Polish
});
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks!